# How to Implement real-time chatting using node.js and Socket.io in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, react-native

I am looking for resources to guide me across server-side (Mostly) and client-side. I have referred this resource [Simple Real Time chat app](https://hackernoon.com/a-simple-messaging-app-with-react-native-and-socket-io-e1cae3df7bda). But I am not getting significant results.

I locally hosted this server-side script [index.js](https://github.com/vinnyoodles/react-native-socket-io-example/blob/master/server/index.js) with port number 3000. I ran this script using `node index.js`.Parallelly, I ran the [react-native code](https://github.com/vinnyoodles/react-native-socket-io-example/blob/master/client/index.js) (Android Platform) and made sure that socket.io listens the port number 3000. But when i do any sought of communication from the server side or client side, i am not getting any results.

Comment: You could use the official tutorial? https://socket.io/get-started/chat for the server. The client side concepts in the tutorial should be translatable to React.

Answer (score 5):

Let me know if these links are will help as resources:

- [Simple Chat App](https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088)
- [The GitHub to the above mentioned Chat App](https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp)
- [React Native Chat App](https://blog.callstack.io/simple-chat-app-with-react-native-part-i-34d6ea4c2535)
- [Node.JS Websocket Chat App](https://itnext.io/building-a-node-js-websocket-chat-app-with-socket-io-and-react-473a0686d1e1)
- [Android, NodeJs, and Socket.io ChatApp](https://dev.to/medaymentn/creating-a-realtime-chat-app-with-android--nodejs-and-socketio-4o55)

Comment: The Third link is promising. I'll get back once i get any success. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I read the code and I can't say what exactly is the problem but I will give some advice

in server code user `createServer` method instead of `server` in

```
var server = http.Server(app);
```

in client code try to defer(stall) the use of any method on the socket for the next tick in the event loop using a fake non-sense setTimeout like

....new Socket

....setTimeout(() => { ...socket.emit  }, 0)

because this will garantes the socket is well connected and you didn't use the emit on non-ready socket

I've tried using socket.IO once in react-native it works great back then.I wonder what could possible go wrong in your case!

try at least with a smaller example app then find out if there is any problem with this one.

and a piece of advice..check Rocket.chat and if you find it suitable I can help you with building the client cheerfully

Answer (score 2):

Please consider use Firebase for this. Check these links:

[How To Build A Chat App With React Native](https://blog.expo.io/how-to-build-a-chat-app-with-react-native-3ef8604ebb3c)

[Build a chat app with Firebase and Redux tutorial](https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/chat-app-firebase-redux-react-native/)

[This one is a complete functional app](https://github.com/rubygarage/react-native-firebase-chat)